# No puedo predecir nuevas observaciones con predict()

Tags: r

Ok entonces tengo los siguientes datos:

```
A<-c(.04,.10,.16,.28,.04,.10,.16,.28,.04,.10,.16,.28)
Gain<-c(680.2,721.4,750.4,789.4,672.2,709.2,731.2,778.2,668.4,715.6,732.0,794.0)
```

Entonces quiero predecir una nueva observaciones que es .20 usando un modelo de regresión lineal simple, entonces hago:

```
new.dat<-data.frame(porcentaje=.20)
predict(lm(Gain~A), newdata=new.dat, interval="confidence")
```

Pero lo único que obtengo son todas las predicciones de las observaciones y un mensaje de error:

```
        fit      lwr      upr
1  680.4533 671.1511 689.7555
2  707.9181 701.1857 714.6505
3  735.3829 729.2931 741.4726
4  790.3124 779.3810 801.2437
5  680.4533 671.1511 689.7555
6  707.9181 701.1857 714.6505
7  735.3829 729.2931 741.4726
8  790.3124 779.3810 801.2437
9  680.4533 671.1511 689.7555
10 707.9181 701.1857 714.6505
11 735.3829 729.2931 741.4726
12 790.3124 779.3810 801.2437
Warning message:
'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 12 rows
```

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, por favor ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que no estas construyendo correctamente el `data.frame` de prueba, estás haciendo:

```
new.dat<-data.frame(porcentaje=.20)
```

Este `data.frame` no se corresponde con el que usaste para crear el modelo, lo correcto según tu ejemplo sería nombrar la columna `porcentaje` tal como la has denominado en el `data.frame` de entrenamiento, por ejemplo:

```
new.dat<-data.frame(A=.20)
predict(lm(Gain~A), newdata=new.dat, interval="confidence")

       fit      lwr     upr
1 753.6927 746.6284 760.757
```